# How to increment up between 0 and 1 with scss

Tags: sass

In regards to SCSS, the following generates 2 classes for me between 0 and 1

```scss
  @for $i from 0 through 1 {
    .op-#{1 * $i} {
      opacity: #{1 * $i};
    }
  }
```

which results in

```css
.op-0 {
  opacity: 0;
}
.op-1 {
  opacity: 0.1;
}
```

but how can I get

```scss
.op-0 {
  opacity:0;
}
.op-01 {
  opacity:0.1;
}
.op-02 {
  opacity:0.2;
}

//...etc...

.op-1 {
  opacity:1.0;
}
```

I tried the following...

```scss
  @for $i from 0 through 1 {
    .op-#{0.10 * $i} { //I know this part is wrong - not sure how to do this correctly...
      opacity: #{.10 * $i};
    }
  }
```

but it throws an error.  Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- If you do not want specific classname requirements then you can try below solutions, it will be just that your compiled css classnames will starts from `.opacity1` to `.opacity2`.
- All you need is loop thought 10 times.

```scss
  @for $i from 1 through 10 { //means start from i=1 to till i=10, generate below css
    .op-#{1 * $i} {
      opacity: #{$i/10};
    }
  }
```

- In `sass` for loop valid number after **from** is starting value of loop and whatever valid number we write after **through** is ending point.
- `@for $i from 1 through 10`, this statement means start from 1 till 10.
- `opacity: #{$i/10};`, just logic for generating expected opacity value.

Comment: That is good enough, and for anyone using a modern version of sass, you can also do `  opacity: #{calc($i / 10)};` for the math process. Many thanks!